# Add additional whitelist domain at run-time without restarting the web site

Tags: servicestack

I use this method to add whitelist sites to my multi-tenant SaaS web site's api service:

```
   var whiteListCollection = new List<string>() {"http://localhost:1195","http://blah.com", "http://foo.net" };

var corsFeature = new CorsFeature(
               allowOriginWhitelist: whiteListCollection,
               allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
               allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With",
               allowCredentials: true);

            Plugins.Add(corsFeature);
```

As new customers are provisioned through an admin interface I'd like to be able to update this whitelist without having to re-start the web site (where the whiteListCollection is then recreated from database records of customers).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate Plugins collection wherever you want in your code like this:

```
public void Toto()
{
    var plugin = EndpointHost.Plugins.FirstOrDefault(p => p is CorsFeature) as CorsFeature;
    if (plugin != null)
    {
        EndpointHost.Plugins.Remove(plugin);
    }
    var whiteListCollection = new List<string>() { "http://localhost:1195", "http://blah.com", "http://foo.net" };

    var corsFeature = new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: whiteListCollection,
    allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With",
    allowCredentials: true);
    EndpointHost.Plugins.Add(corsFeature);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for.  Instead of removing and adding a new instance of the plugin with updated whitelists can I just update the allowOriginWhiteList property of the plugin?  I ask this because I am concerned about the transactional aspect of someone hitting the service exactly during the split second that the plugin has been removed.

Comment: With ServiceStack v4 you can manipulate collection directly through CorsFeature.AllowOriginWhitelist https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs

Comment: In ServiceStack v3 it was not possible to manipulate this collection https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Cors/CorsFeature.cs

Answer (score 2):

The `CorsFeature` in [ServiceStack v4.0.21](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#v4021-release-notes) now lets you access the [AllowOriginWhitelist](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs#L27) property, so it can be modified with:

```
var corsFeature = HostContext.GetPlugin<CorsFeature>();
corsFeature.AllowOriginWhitelist.Add(newUrl);
```